# Telerik grid showing non-existent columns ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, gridview, dynamic, telerik, advanced-custom-fields

i am prepairing sample report screen,
user will choose report from dropdownBox   and fill some special options.
after it click search Button (Sorgula)  it hits Read action from ReportController.

this Controller Returns List (whatever you whish)  as Json

now this is working.
But Telerik Grid adding different columns which i have never added to result.

There are no columns on grid defined by me. because columns Must occur according to json result

Now My Grid Create Query

```
$("#ReportResult").kendoGrid({
        selectable: "multiple cell",
        allowCopy: true,
        height: 550,
        groupable: true,
        pageable: true,
        sortable: true,

        pageable: {
             input: true,
            numeric: false
        },

        dataSource: new kendo.data.GanttDataSource({
            pageSize: 20,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
             transport: {
            read: {
                url: '<%= Url.Action("Read", "Report") %>',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    ReportID: 1,
                    OrganizationID: 2,
                    StartDate: "22",
                    EndDate: "11",
                    UserName:"dds",
                },
            },
        },

        }),


    });
```

Read action

```
public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int ReportID,int OrganizationID,string StartDate,string EndDate,string UserName)
    {

        List<COnsumersReport> lis = new List<COnsumersReport>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            COnsumersReport cc = new COnsumersReport();
            cc.ID = i;
            cc.name = "semih";
            cc.sirname = "Yıldız";
            cc.Borc =i*20.5;
            lis.Add(cc);
        }


        return Json(lis);
    }
```

And the result.  As you see id,parentId,orderId,Title vs has not defined by me.

[image]

```
    public class COnsumersReport
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string  name { get; set; }
        public string sirname { get; set; }
        public double Borc { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942205/stop-kendo-from-auto-generating-grid-columns

Comment: thank you @PierreLebon
but this is not for me. Because i dont know which column names will come from datasource .

this grid  should show all the lists of objects

Comment: Does the COnsumersReport object have all of these extra properties?  If so, then you are defining them when you call new COnsumersReport().  Use a different object to bind to that only contains your desired fields.

Comment: @Seano666  COnsumersReport have only    4 columns

Comment: Can you post the code with which you are declaring your grid in the view?  That is an important component that you've left out.  #ReportResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was grid datasource . i have used to kendo.data.GanttDataSource 
grand datasource adding auto columns.

when i try to use kendo.data.DataSource problem is fixed.

```
 dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        pageSize: 100,
        serverPaging: true,
            transport: {
                read:  {
                    url: '<%= Url.Action("Read", "Report") %>',
                    dataType: "json", 
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        ReportID: $('#Rapor').val(),
                        OrganizationID: $('#Organizations').val(),
                        StartDate: $('#datepicker').val(),
                        EndDate: $('#datepickerEndDate').val(),
                        UserName: $('#userName').val(),
                    },                        
                },                    
            },
        error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error Verdi" + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        },
        schema: {
            total: function (response) {
            return ResultCount;
            } 
        }
       }),
```